# Geolocation API permission pop-up twice

Tags: html, ios

If you refresh the page after initially granting location permission, you will be prompted for location permission again and will need to grant permission again. Currently this issue only occurs on iOS. Is there a way?

For reference, I am running a web as a hybrid app, but the Safari settings did not solve the problem.

iOS versions tested are 16.2 and 17.

This is the code implemented when retrieving location information.

```
<script>
        var options = {
            timeout: 15000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 86400000,
        };

        function success(pos) {
            var crd = pos.coords;

            alert('Your current position is:');
            alert(`Latitude : `+crd.latitude);
            alert(`Longitude: `+crd.longitude);
        };

        function error(err) {
            alert(`ERROR(): `+err.message);
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
</script>
```

I recreated the project from scratch, modified the source in various ways, and tested it, but it didn't work.